# What's the correct way to delegate failable initializers in Swift?

Tags: swift

Say I have this class:

```
class EvenNumber {
  var num: Int
  var stringValue: String

  init?(n: Int) {
    guard n % 2 == 0 else { return nil }
    self.num = n
  }

  init?(str: String) {
    guard let n = Int(str) else { return nil }
    self.init(n: n)
    //set stringValue?
  }
}
```

In the `init` that takes a string, I delegate back to the one that takes an `Int`. How do I know whether it succeeded so I can continue initialization? What's the proper syntax / common pattern here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to check that the delegated initialiser has succeeded. If the delegated initialiser has failed, the whole initialisation process fails.

This is evident in this code:

```
class EvenNumber {
  var num: Int
  var stringValue: String

  init?(n: Int) {
    guard n % 2 == 0 else { return nil }
    self.num = n
    stringValue = "" // you forgot to initialise stringValue in both of your initialisers
  }

    // you forgot "convenience"
  convenience init?(str: String) {
    guard let n = Int(str) else { return nil }
    self.init(n: n)
    print("hello")
    stringValue = ""
  }
}

EvenNumber(str: "5")
```

"hello" does not get printed, which means that the rest of the `init(str:)` does not get executed if `init(n:)` fails.

[Here's](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html#ID224) some supporting documentation (you need to scroll down a bit, under "Propagation of Initialization Failure"):

> In either case, if you delegate to another initializer that causes initialization to fail, the entire initialization process fails immediately, and no further initialization code is executed.

---

(This section is included for completeness' sake.)

Now you (or whoever comes to this question in the future) might ask, "but what if I want to do something else if the delegated initialiser *fails*?" In that case, you must check for the condition that causes the initialiser to fail:

```
if n % 2 == 1 {
    self.init(n: n)
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

Why is this so "clumsy"? Well, let's say you *could* do this (warning: made-up syntax):

```
if self.init(n: n) {
    // success!
} else {
    // fail
}
```

To get to the "fail" branch, we must have already run `self.init(n:)`. `self.init(n:)`, before it failed, might have already initialised some `let` properties. Recall that `let` properties can only be initialised once. So now `self.init(n: n)` has been executed, but the compiler doesn't know which `let` properties have been initialised. See the problem? How is the compiler going to verify that you have initialised every property exactly once in the "fail" branch?